# VueJs - Include a button after a v-select

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm quite a newby using Bootstrap-Vue for a project,
I have a structure like this

```
<template>
  <v-select>
    <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
      <div class="d-center">
        {{ option.name }}
      </div>
    </template>
  </v-select>
</template>
```

and I want to put a  `<b-button></b-button>` after the v-select closure, but I get an error, I'm not sure why honestly.

Comment: You mean just before like this: `</b-button> <v-select>` or wrap the `<v-select>` with the `b-button></b-button>`

Comment: see [input-group](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/input-group)

Comment: in Vue2 you can only have 1 root element in the template tag - that means, that a `v-select` is 1, `b-button` is 2 - NOT OK. You have to wrap them in something (like a `div`). And there's no `v-select` in BootstrapVue. Vuetify has `v-select`. But if you are using Vuetify, then you need `v-btn` (it has no `b-button`).

Comment: the project it's using Vuetify, it's right. I tried `<v-btn>`, wrapping both inside a `<div>` but I get some different errors on the select element.

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify has slots to append elements.  There are several.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#slots

```html
<v-select>
  <template #append>
    <v-btn>Your Button</v-btn>
  </template>
</v-select>
```